# Visual Studio Code debugger: launch.json The property 'program' is invalid

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

**1.** Setup: I have installed Visual Studio code on My Ubuntu and installed [.NET Core](http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/#/linux) and Mono.

**2.** Intial Configuration: I created a simple demo app running `notnet restore` and `dotnet run`. This simply works fine and display "Hello World!" on terminal.

**3.** Extension: To debug this, I installed extension of **OmniSharp**. and then using "Debugger" option of Visual Studio Code, I added **launch.json** & **task.json**.

**4.** launch.json (Only showing configuration section):

```
....
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netstandardapp1.5/hwAppCore2.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false
    }    
....
```

**5.** Now, when running from terminal it works fine, however when try to debug using option **.NET Core Launch (console)** I am getting following error:

**"launch: The property 'program' is invalid. '/home/ak/dotnet_core/hwAppCore2/bin/Debug/netstandardapp1.5/hwAppCore2.dll' is a library (.dll), not a program."**

I also followed one of [Channel 9 demo](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/John-Kemnetz-C-debugging-in-VS-Code), and there also I can see hwapp.dll configured for program property of **launch.json**

I am not sure, am I missing anything to configure?

Comment: You should launch `dotnet` with the arguments `run <path to dll>`

Comment: I can run my application properly from terminal using `dotnet run`, However I am having issues with debugging option from **vscode**.

Comment: I updated path in launch.json's program property as "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netstandardapp1.5/ubuntu.14.04-x64/hwAppCore2" - (added folder **ubuntu.14.04-x64** and removed **.dll**) and debugging started properly.

Is it the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after raising an issue with [OmniSharp on GitHub](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/290).

Solution paths provided by **@gregg-miskelly**, follow path 1 for daily build to get answer to exactly what my question was and path 2 for recommended build which works as per earlier comment.

Comment: Also, with latest RC2, debugging is supported. Please upgrade latest RC2 accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several hoops you have to jump through to get VS Code debugging .NET Core websites. The relevant steps (from [this blog post walkthrough](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/cross-platform-asp-net-core-debugging-visual-studio-code/)) are:

- Install [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) and the .NET Debugger (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd>, "Download .NET Core Debugger")
- Open your project folder - it should prompt you to add build tasks

  - (creates `.vscode > tasks.json`)
- Open the Debug tab from the sidebar, click the 'Settings' button, and choose ".NET Core"

  - (creates `.vscode > launch.json`) with 3 configurations - "console", "web", and "attach".
- Open the `launch.json` file and edit the "web" configuration's `program` value - replace the `<>` placeholders with your specific values (e.g. `netcoreapp1.0` and `MyProject.dll`).

  - (This is the step the OP needed to do)
  - For some reason VS Code doesn't handle the placeholders for web projects... I haven't been able to find any documentation / explanation why yet
- Edit the `project.json` file - under `buildOptions`, add `"debugType" : "portable"`
- Run `dotnet restore` on your project to get the latest packages
- Start debugging!